# Whistleblowing on Waste

Tags: whistle-blowing

**Disclaimer:** This is a theoretical question.

### Assumptions

When an individual directly witnesses, has evidence of, or has a credible suspicion of *wrongdoing* at their place of work or in any organization with some* level of interaction with or involvement by the state, whether the *wrongdoing* is performed by another individual or the organization as a whole, they should, must, or are strongly encouraged to, use whatever whistleblower systems at their disposal to report the *wrongdoing*.

### Summary of question

It is, or at least should be, clear what the outcomes of stealing even a single dollar will be.
However, working in such a way that even millions of dollars are *wasted* as a result of deliberate actions that go against industry best-practices, even if it is clearly ***known or should have been known*** that such actions will be wasteful, do not have a clear outcome in whistleblowing or whether whistleblowing would even encompass these situations.

Is this an issue of the Whistleblowing regime not being implemented incorrectly, not encompassing 'waste', or is it an issue of the burden of proof being so high that it would essentially and practically never be possible to prove *wrongdoing*?

**Note**: All persons in the examples are employees at the same organization.

###### Example 1

**Scenario:** Person A witnesses person B stealing 1 dollar from the an organizations customer.
**Reaction:** Person A blows the whistle on Person B for stealing 1 dollar from the an organizations customer.
**Expected Outcome:** Person B is prosecuted for theft.

###### Example 2

**Scenario:** Person A witnesses person B taking 100 dollar from the an organizations itself.
**Reaction:** Person A blows the whistle on Person B for taking 100 dollar from the an organizations itself.
**Expected Outcome:** Person B is prosecuted for theft.

#### Examples in Question

###### Example: 3

**Scenario:** Person A witnesses person B actively, over time, consistently performing actions that lowers productivity at an organization. The actions are clearly against industry best-practices.
**Reaction:** Person A blows the whistle on Person B for actively working against the organization best interests.
**Expected Outcome:** ?

###### Example: 4

**Scenario:** Person A witnesses organization B actively, over time, consistently performing actions that lowers productivity at the organization. The actions are clearly against industry best-practices.
**Reaction:** Person A blows the whistle on organization B for actively working against the best interests of their customers.
**Expected Outcome:** ?

Comment: Aren't your second Example 1 and Example 2 identical?

Comment: It's extremely unlikely that the first example 1 results in the police being called and a prosecution made. In some environments it might result in the employee being disciplined. Prosecution is not that likely even in first example 2.

Comment: You misunderstand the term "whistleblowing", It's defined as reporting something that is " illegal, immoral, illicit, unsafe or fraudulent". Running your business poorly does not fall into any of these categories. The difference is in to WHOM you report. Whistleblowers will typically contact the relevant authorities (police, SEC, FDA, etc)  or the media. Any type of governance issue is an internal problem.

Answer (score 1):

**There are are whole pile of differences between the first case (theft) and second case (alleged poor practice).** Here are a few.

1. Theft is unquestionably detrimental to the company. "Poor" working practices are not. Even if they are "clearly against industry best-practices", industry best practices are not always ideal in every circumstance. Before "whistle-blowing" here you would have to be extremely sure that these practices were really hurting the company. (It would be a different story if you are in a regulated profession, for example an accountant using non-standard accounting practices - but that is a matter of regulation).
2. Theft is something people do to benefit themselves, and only incidentally hurts the company. Alleged poor practice is very different. Unless you are alleging that this person is deliberately doing something with the purpose of harming the company, which would be extremely difficult to prove.
3. "Poor" working practices are often offset by other factors. Maybe this employee is so familiar with their "non-standard" way of doing things that they are much more productive doing it that way. Maybe they are doing it to accommodate another worker.
4. Some things that look like poor working practices actually aren't. You mustn't jump to judgement and punishment because you see something you think is not the best way of doing things.
5. All employees know and understand that theft is wrong. Not all employees know that "poor working practices" are wrong (and even if they are told, not all believe it). The first approach to seeing what you think is sub-standard work should be investigation and education, not punishment.
6. Even if the way of working is sub-optimal, trying to fix it may have bad side-effects. If you call out this employee, and this irritates them so much they quit, and they are twice as productive an employee as you are, then the company is worse off because of what you did. If they threaten to quit, and are twice as productive as you, then you may find yourself looking for a job yourself - because that's the best result for the company.

Finally the term "whistle-blowing" is used for reporting *company* malfeasance, not individual workers. You don't "whistle-blow" on one person's behaviour.

If you see someone who is performing less well than you think they could, and you think this is having a serious affect on the company, then you should a) talk to them about it if they are a peer or report to you; find out why they are doing it an gently suggest an alternate approach b) talk to their boss or their peer if they are superior to you. In both cases make sure you investigate rather than accuse.

If it's not having a significant affect on the company then take option c) mind your own business.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to write a response to the post, and for the details. I would however like to point out that I specifically did not write "poor working practice" for all the reasons you have mentioned, but rather "actively, over time, consistently performing actions that lowers productivity at the organization". While I see distinction there, others might not, which is of course acceptable. Thank you again for participating in the discussion.

Comment: The difference in wording makes absolutely no difference to my answer.